# Arduino Wifi Shield server not responding

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to set up a web server on a Wifi shield following the example here http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WiFiWebServer

I'm connecting over WPA.  I just have the wifi shield sat on top of an Arduino Uno, no wires connected.

I upload the code with my network details.  Green light shows on the wifi shield, everything seems fine.  Serial monitor reads:

Attempting to connect to SSID: NETGEAR69
SSID: NETGEAR69
IP Address: 192.168.0.7
signal strength (RSSI):-65 dBm

But when I go to 192.168.0.7 in a browser (I've tried this on my computer on my home network and on my phone's 3G network as well, same results) nothing will load.  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What you have looks good. The server is responding as expected.

Is there an SD card inserted? The page you refer to suggests removing it or setting the mode of pin 4 to output to prevent the sketch from hanging.

The only other thing to suggest is change the html output to the client. The sketch in the tutorial doesn't output conforming html as there are no head and body tags. Perhaps add such tags and simplify the output by replacing the contents of the if block

```
      // send a standard http response header
      client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
      client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
      client.println("Connection: close");  // the connection will be closed after completion of the response
      client.println("Refresh: 5");  // refresh the page automatically every 5 sec
      client.println();
      client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
      client.println("<html>");
      // output the value of each analog input pin
      for (int analogChannel = 0; analogChannel < 6; analogChannel++) {
        int sensorReading = analogRead(analogChannel);
        client.print("analog input ");
        client.print(analogChannel);
        client.print(" is ");
        client.print(sensorReading);
        client.println("<br />");       
      }
      client.println("</html>");
      break;
```

with

```
      // send a standard http response header
      client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
      client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
      client.println();
      client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
      client.println("<html><head></head><body><h1>Hello, World!!</h1></body></html>");
      break;
```

Comment: There's no card inserted, and I tried the output code.
I'm afraid the same problem exists with the alternative html code.  Any other ideas to try?  I'm completely stumped with this.